# Bind triple left click to mouse wheel click using xbindkeysrc?

Tags: 14.04, mouse, xbindkeys

I want my middle mouse button, button 2, to create a triple left click event (highlight a line). When I use xbindkeys -n -v it registers the triple click event but it doesn't appear to work/register with anything else. I do restart xbindkeys in the background after testing with xbindkeys -n -v.

Below is the relevant line in my xbindkeysrc file:

```
    "xte 'mouseclick 1' 'mouseclick 1' 'mouseclick 1'"
    b:2
```

And here is the output of xbinkeys -n -v

```
    "xte 'mouseclick 1' 'mouseclick 1' 'mouseclick 1'"
m:0x0 + b:2   (mouse)
    got screen 0 for window 293
    Start program with fork+exec call
    Button press !
    e.xbutton.button=1
    e.xbutton.state=528
    Button release !
    e.xbutton.button=1
    e.xbutton.state=784
    Button press !
    e.xbutton.button=1
    e.xbutton.state=528
    Button release !
    e.xbutton.button=1
    e.xbutton.state=784
    Button press !
    e.xbutton.button=1
    e.xbutton.state=528
    Button release !
    e.xbutton.button=1
   e.xbutton.state=784
   Button release !
   e.xbutton.button=2
   e.xbutton.state=528
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're still holding down button 2 when button 1 is being sent, and the two interfere. You only need to change

> b:2

to

> b:2+Release

(i.e. execute upon release of button 2), and it should work.